# CSS for the "down arrow" on a <select> element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to stylize the down arrow on a drop down select element? i.e., (`<select><option>--></option></select>`)

I suspect the answer is no because of the way IE handles that particular element. If there isn't a way, does anyone know of a 'fake' drop down box using javaScript that would mimic that behavior but give me the ability to customize?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you can use [jQuery selectbox replacement](http://code.google.com/p/select-box/). It's a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Works perfect for me :)
I think there is no better solution for this, cause of a lot of problems with IE and CSS hacking...
The only thing I am missing here is a fall back to some sort of css if JS is disabled in the browser.

Comment: If css is disabled your users deserve what they get.

Answer (score 49):

There's a cool CSS-only solution to styling dropdowns here: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Basically, wrap the select in a container div, style the select to be 18px wider than the container with a transparent background, give overflow:hidden to the container (to chop off the browser-generated arrow), and add your background image with stylized arrow to the container.

Doesn't work in IE7 (or 6), but seriously, I say if you're using IE7 you deserve a less-pretty dropdown experience.

Comment: I used this to render select tag for a mobile site ... I did not use javascript to keep the default os behaviour popping dialog ... rendering okey [iphone;android 3/4] dev still in progress though

Answer (score 5):

No, the down arrow is a browser element. It's built in [and different] in every browser. You can, however, replace the select box with a custom drop down box using javascript.

Jan Hancic mentioned a jQuery plugin to do just that.

Answer (score 3):

The drop-down is platform-level element, you can't apply CSS to it.

You can overlay an image on top of it using CSS, and call the click event in the element beneath.

Answer (score 3):

You can't style combos very well using CSS.

The guys at FogBugz made a pretty good custom combo using JavaScript, so it is possible, it just takes a lot of work to get it right.

Better to stick with the standard one for version 1, then see if it's worth updating it once your app is in the wild.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is stylable with CSS (probably not in IE), but please: do not use a "fake" drop-down box using javascript, because the usability of these things usually is horrible. Among other things, keyboard navigation is usually absent.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with just CSS and your down arrow as an image positioned absolute with a "pointer-events: none;" see my example below:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1 Person</option>
  <option value="2">2 People</option>
</select>
<img class="passthrough" src="downarrow.png" />

.passthrough {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own dropdown using hidden divs and a hidden input element to record which option was "selected". My guess is that @Jan Hancic's link he posted is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <div style='position:relative;left:0px;top:0px;
        onMouseOver=document.getElementById('visible').style.visibility='visible' 
        id='hidden'>10
   <select style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;cursor:pointer;visibility:hidden;'
        onMouseOut=document.getElementById('visible').style.visibility='hidden'
        onChange='this.form.submit()' 
        id='visible' multiple size='3'>";
   <option selected value=10>10</option>
   <option value=20>20</option>
   <option value=50>50</option>
   </select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change inputs, select etc to the old style grey not sure if you can manipulate after that:
In `<head>` put:

```
<meta http-equiv="MSThemeCompatible" content="NO">
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/u3cybk2q/2/ check on windows, iOS and Android (iexplorer patch)

```css
.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 240px;
   padding: 5px;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1;
   border: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   height: 34px;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.styled-select {
   width: 240px;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: visible;
   background: url(http://nightly.enyojs.com/latest/lib/moonstone/dist/moonstone/images/caret-black-small-down-icon.png) no-repeat right #FFF;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.styled-select select::-ms-expand {
    display: none; /*patch iexplorer*/
}
```

```html
  <div class="styled-select">
       <select>
          <option>Here is the first option</option>
          <option>The second option</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```