# Moving the arrow position on a <select> menu

Tags: html, css, select

Is it possible to move the dropdown arrow on a select box from right to left with CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** just as I suspected this changes the text direction of the `option`s in the list as well, so you can't use `direction`. Besides that, there isn't any other way than to use a custom drop-down control. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element). I'll just leave my original answer below for anyone curious.

---

<del>You should be able to</del> use the [`direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-direction) property, but I haven't verified if this works across browsers, platforms and locales:

```
select { direction: rtl; }
```

Be careful when using `direction` though, as the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#direction) advises against its use by anyone but DTD authors or authors of special documents:

> Because the directionality of a text depends on the structure and semantics of the document language, these properties should in most cases be used only by designers of document type descriptions (DTDs), or authors of special documents. If a default style sheet specifies these properties, authors and users should not specify rules to override them.

Comment: ah, but it's then switching the text to the right, which I don't want