# Styling the arrow of a <select> element?

Tags: html, css

How would you style the color of only the arrow of a  element?

The "Background color" attribute alters the color of both the text and the arrow. I just want to color the arrow.

Example of a select element with a green backgrounded arrow on iOS
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS for the "down arrow" on a <select> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element)

Comment: Beware of heavily styled quasi-select elements. They're usually div tags in disguise. Select elements are very difficult to style beyond positioning since they're so heavily reliant on implementation. You're either going to be looking towards a pre-baked solution or a bunch of hacky CSS/JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The default SELECT is a form element rendered by the browser and/or OS.

What you have to do is built-your-own akin to something like this:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a way to change the native select element.

I think you must create it by your self using some JS or the much easier way use a jQuery UI plugin, like this: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

This question has been here before, see [Is it possible to style a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072239/is-it-possible-to-style-a-select-box) which roughly gives the same answer.