# css for drop list menu arrow

Tags: css, html

How do i change the default arrow of the drop list box to a different arrow design using css?

```
<select name="menu">
  <option>list1</option>
  <option>list2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't do that to native forms elements, they are generally poorly stylable through css.

Answer (score 0):

If found [this](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) in [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element) (was not the correct answer). I think is what you want

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin in jQuery called, [`jQuery SelectBox Plugin`](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/jquery-selectbox-plugin/). It replaces your native select box and replaces it with a customisable one.

See a demo of the plugin here.