# Why is a <select> sometimes white and sometimes gray?

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

Why is a `<select>` dropdown element (the **arrow**) sometimes white and sometimes gray?

**I have this sample code:**

```
<html>
  <body>

    <select>
      <option>1</option>
    </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

*When I'm testing the code as a .html page in IE 9, the result looks like this:*

http://img0.www.suckmypic.net/img/7/n/xaxKK6g5/IEresult1.png

*And when I'm testing the code with JSFiddle in IE 9, the result looks like this:*

http://img0.www.suckmypic.net/img/A/h/S4o4tOP7/IEresult2.png

**Why? And how can i force the select to be "gray"?**

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/VuSWz/

Comment: Maybe the difference is that JSFiddle puts a <!doctype> above your code, forcing IE in a different rendering mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS for the "down arrow" on a <select> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element)

Comment: I see two broken images.

Comment: The images look the same. What's the problem? `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like on of your comments said, you have 2 render modes.

Look @ this Question.

[CSS for the "down arrow" on a <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element)

Here you can learn how to have the same drop down arrows with the help of css code.

Hope i could help you.

Regards