# Styling DropDownList ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, html-select

Hi I am trying to make my `DropDownList` like this in my `ASP.NET` web application.

[image]

I cant't use the `select` tag because I am already bounded some data to the DropDownList.
Basically I am trying to remove the default arrow button from the `DropDownList` and add this image as background. There is any way to do this using `CSS`.
This is the css I have used

```
.drop-down-style
{
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
  border:solid 2px #a3a4a6;
  background-image:url('../Images/DropDownImage.gif');
}
```

Comment: http://www.noupe.com/css/form-elements-40-cssjs-styling-and-functionality-techniques.html
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/example/
http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/ But know that may not work in all browsers

Comment: I think your question can be answered here:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

CSS:

```
.styled-select {
    width: 308px;
    height: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:url(arrow_xs.png) no-repeat 225px #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.styled-select select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 309px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <select>
        <option>First option</option>
        <option>Second option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

edit: You can add an arrow with positioning (div).

**edit**  I put this in a jsfiddle for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/X4J3L/1/

Answer (score 0):

rather then use some third party plugins or jquery scripts , you should use ajax toolkit's combo box. see an example here

[Combo box example](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx)