# drop down not looking common in ie8 & ie9

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

html:

```
<span align="left" class="section_span" >
<label for="gender">Gender</label><br />
<select id="gender" name="gender" class="select-input">
<option value="">Gender</option>
<option value="M">Male</option>
<option value="F">Female</option>
</select><br /><br />
</span>
```

css:

```
.select-input{
    width:180px;  
    padding:5px;
    font-family: "Helvetica-Light";
    font-size: 9pt;
    color:#2a2a2a;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    background: #ffffff url("../images/select-arrow.png") no-repeat;
    background-position:143px center;
    overflow:hidden;
}

  border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin; 
    border-color: #DDDDDD;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.section_span{
    width:190px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right:11px;
}
```

I am getting the drop down arrow like in the screen shot in chrome and FF(showing both side arrow).But in ie8 and ie9  it is showing only downward arrow and not showing both up and down arrow as shown in chrome and FF.How to solve this[image].

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS for the "down arrow" on a <select> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element)

Comment: More possible solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow

Answer (score 0):

What about having your customized `dropdown` box??

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkin/dGTg3/4/)</kbd>