# simple select box jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Can anyone please recommend a simple jQuery plugin which will allow me, with minimal fuss, to replace the down arrow on a select box with my own image.

I've found LOADS of plugins, either they have so many configurable options that they are to complicated to use, or the are impossible to style properly, or something else which makes them unworkable for me.

It can't be that hard to do this. Surely there's a simple little plugin out there somewhere?

ps I don't want to use the parentWrapper being narrower than my input with overflow:hidden. It won't work in my circumstance.

Any help would be gratefully received, I've probably seen 50 plugins, tried about 10 and taken about 5 hours to do so so far. It really can't be that complicated can it?

:( Sarah

Comment: It seems that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458657/css-for-the-down-arrow-on-a-select-element) might answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is very good and simple: http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/